# Почему не работает кнопка "удалить"?

Tags: php, html, запрос, mysqli

Добрый день.
вывод из массива в таблицу работает.
По идее должна быть реализована кнопка "удалить где id равен id строки в массиве"
Не работает следующая конструкция

```
<?
            while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $record['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $record['number']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $record['description']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $record['id']; ?><button> <? 
                            $delete= mysqli_query ($connection, 'delete from letPhone where "id" = ($record["id"]')?>удалить</button></td>
                    <tr>
                <?
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Кажется, в таком синтаксисе надо использовать `:` - `end...`  И конструкция выбора в скобки не взята

Comment: Попробовал с "end" но результат тот же. Ошибок нет, но удаление не работает.
По поводу скобок нужна помощь... вроде верно все (но я могу ошибаться). "id" = (массив["индекс массива]") так же?

Comment: @BeerAndBear   у вас же в  представленном коде удаление в цикле ?так не бывает , есть обычный name вот на него надо повесть обработчик php , а код на то как удалять есть в mysql

Comment: @Максим Ленский так код не инициирован. 
я хотел следующего (грубо)
123   123    123   22(id)  кнопка (удалить id 22)
123   123    123   23 кнопка (удалить id 23)

как то так. 
после нажатия страница перезагружается с уже удаленной строкой.

Comment: PHP это серверный язык, а вы пытаетесь на клиенте сделать удаление. Вам нужно использовать либо JS - аякс запрос на сервер через который передавать ID записи которую нужно удалить (более правильно) либо каждую строку таблицы помещать в форму где будет скрытое поле с  ID и кнопка отправки формы на сервер (не очень правильно).

Comment: Почитайте в сети или посмотрите как делается удаление , к примеру на youtube видео по данному вопросу вагон

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk мда. именно второй вариант я и пытался сделать.


Всем спасибо)  буду пробовать через аякс)

Comment: @ Beer And Bear Тогда у вас кнопка должна была быть `<input type="submit" >`, а не `button` ну и скрытое поле в котором указано  ID записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `button` должен иметь действие. У Вас в кнопку выводится, даже нет, просто подставляется результат запроса к БД скриптом  РНР.

2) Вы на кнопку (клиентская часть) вешаете скрипты РНР (серверная часть). Так быть не должно. Кнопка должна передавать на сервер данные, а сервер их обрабатываеть. Два-в-одном не получится...

Comment: может я неправильно выразился. Я имел ввиду что в каждой строке будет кнопка "удалить строку №id"   и так на каждом выводе.

Comment: Да что тут неправильного в выражении? Все понятно - не работает. Причин много - читайте выше ответы и комменты

Comment: Вот теперь вернувшись в прошлое я понял насколько был неправ и глуп)))